# Custom CSS border styles (this one is tricky!)

Tags: css, border

I have a tricky CSS border I want to style. Essentially I want to achieve this border effect for a div, where the div height is 10px with a 1px solid green border, but the right border has an overlay of 4px solid red, which is vertically-centers and only 5px high.

See below:

[image]

Any bright ideas? I've played around with Pseudo elements but no luck. I want this in a single div.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it's possible in a single div, but who knows!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS3.

```
div {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    background: red;
    width: 3px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

You just have to play around with the pixel value's to make it like you want to have it (your example image doesn't really look like it is 10px x 10px).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use after or before Pseudo for this

```
div:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border:5px solid green;
height: 50px;
left:198px;
top:60px;}
```

fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/zjUZB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Create a div that goes over the green div.
Position it like you want.
Give it this css: `pointer-events:none;`

I doubt this is possible in a single div. Perhaps having an image as the right border, but it means a loss in flexibility for the div size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

```
.your-div:after { content: " "; 
border-left: 10px /*or whatever*/ solid red; 
position: relative;}
```

And set border, width, height, position etc. as you need to them.

Just a quick idea, not yet tested:)

Other than that, I have no idea (CSS does not supports multiple borders).

Oh, I just read that you've played around with pseudo elements aready... So you might have already tried it out.